# gnuplot separate closed numbers

Tags: gnuplot

I often get the following kind of graphs

[image]

Where the numbers of the axis are merged. The question is whether gnuplot can place them on different height, so that they will be distinguishable.

Or may be there is other way to make the graph readable.

Comment: Please post an example of code that produces that.  It is hard to make a recommendation without knowing why you are seeing that.  One of the most common solutions is to rotate the labels slightly.  For example, `set xtics rotate by -45` will rotate them by 45 degrees so that they read diagonally down to the right.  Playing with the angle, you may be able to get them to not overlap.  Different heights may also be possible depending on how the labels are being generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this depending on how the labels are generated.

Suppose that your data looks like

```
39 6
41 7
43 9
52 12
55 15
58 3
62 9
63 7
70 5
76 9
77 2
79 3
```

where I am trying to mimic the labels that you have in your example.

### Approach 1

You can rotate the labels.  The command `set xtics rotate by <angle>` will rotate the labels by the given angle.

For this demonstration, I am going to set the xrange to 20-100, so that I can force labels to overlap like you have shown.  I also will explicitly specify tic marks (gnuplot's auto-generated marks do not often overlap), as I assume you have in your example beings they are not evenly spaced.

If, I just try to plot with `plot datafile u 1:2:xtic(1)`, I am going to get overlapping labels

[image]

If I first issue `set xtics rotate by -50` to rotate the labels by 50 degrees downward, and then plot with

```
plot datafile u 1:2:xtic(1)
```

I will get

[image]

which has significantly less overlap.  Using `set xtics rotate by -90` will cut this further.

### Approach 2

I can add a newline to every other tic mark to adjust heights to help avoid overlap.  This approach will only work if we are explicitly specifying tic marks.

We can define a function by

```
adjustlab(x,y) = (int(x)%2==0?y:sprintf("\n%s",y))
```

This function will take two inputs.  The first is a line number and the second is a label.  It will then add a newline if the line number is odd.

We need to first expand the bottom margin with `set bmargin 3`, and then we can plot with

```
plot datafile u 1:2:xtic(adjustlab($0,strcol(1)))
```

Note that we use the strcol function to read column 1 as a string to feed to our adjusting function.

This produces

[image]

More complicated functions can be constructed to allow more complicated conditions on the adjusting.